# Option to generate a .m4s file every second

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, ip, live

I am trying to stream my live recording from a camera (web cam/ IP cam) to my web application. The streaming technique I use is MPEG-DASH, which has manifest in MPD format. To generate an MPD format from the web-cam, I use FFmpeg tool in shell command line:

```
ffmpeg -re -y -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C525" -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -f dash "manifest.mpd"
```

This code will generate a video chunk in .m4s format every 5-8 seconds.

Question is, what FFmpeg option can I use to generate a .m4s file every second instead of every 5-8 seconds? I suppose it has something to do with segment?

Answer (score 0):

`-seg_duration 1 -ldash 1 -streaming 1` would help you.